# How to check workflow History in Office 365

Tags: designer-workflow, office-365

I've created workflow on SharePoint Designer 2013 and deploye on Office 365. Want to know how to check workflow history for this

Comment: Is the workflow associated with a List or Library? Deploying alone won't create the history list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Workflow History List is hidden by default. You can open it by typing the URL

```
http://sharepointsiteurl/lists/Workflow%20history/AllItems.aspx
```

Or using SharePoint designer

1. Open site in SharePoint Designer
2. From Left Navigation Click All Files
3. Click Lists
4. Right Click Workflow History and Select Properties
5. From the new window uncheck "Hide from browser"
6. Save

Now you can view all site content in browser where the history list will be visible.

Comment: Amal, I'm using Office 365 and already tried first option which is showing page can not be display. For second one this is live site so want to see history only in Designer is it possible.

Comment: @user3760253 You can follow steps 1 to 4 and then click on the Browse icon that is available on the top of the designer.

Comment: THanks for this piece of info. I wonder why the list is not shown by default under site contents :-/